# I want to create an AWS ECS cluster. If I choose the default VPC everything is OK. But if I choose another VPC it does't work

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-cdk, amazon-vpc

I created an ECS cluster with the configuration of Capacity provider as EC2 instances.

[image: How I create a cluster]

I chose a VPC similar to the default VPC. The auto-scaling group minimum size was 1. But when I create the cluster, no EC2 register in the Container instances. However, if I choose the default VPC it works well. What is the reason? This is my code to create a VPC:

```
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import * as ec2 from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-ec2';
import { Construct } from 'constructs';

export class VPC_Stack extends cdk.Stack {

  public readonly vpc: ec2.Vpc; 

  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, stackName: string, appName: string) {
    super(scope, id, {
      stackName: appName + '-' + stackName,  
    });

    const name = appName + '-' + stackName + 'VPC';

    this.vpc = new ec2.Vpc(this, name + '-id', {
      cidr: '10.0.0.0/16',
      maxAzs: 3,
      subnetConfiguration: [
        {
          name: 'PublicSubnetAz1',
          subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC,
          cidrMask: 24,
        }
      ],
      natGateways: 1,
      vpcName: name
    });

  }
}
```

Comment: is this using CDK? Please show a [mre] and be more specific than "doesn't work" do you see an error message?

Comment: Your configuration will not use the nat gateway at all - isolated subnets have no egress.

Comment: I created only public subnet. but I have the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you are deploying the EC2 instances into the `PRIVATE_ISOLATED` subnets? Those subnets have no route to anything outside the VPC, such as the ECS service, so instances in those `PRIVATE_ISOLATED` subnets cannot connect to the ECS service to register with the cluster. You need to do one of the following:

- Add all the necessary [VPC endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/vpc-endpoints.html) to your VPC
- Change that to `PRIVATE_WITH_EGRESS` (which will incur a cost of the NAT Gateways that will be created)
- Deploy your EC2 instances to the PUBLIC subnets instead

---

The default VPC does not have `PRIVATE_ISOLATED` subnets, which explains why you are seeing it work when you deploy to the default VPC.